# Calculating value of series by taking the difference

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Apologies if this is a basic question!

I'm trying to understand a solution to a problem I was solving. The author suggests a trick to calculate expected value by multiplying the expected value series by 0.5 (line 2) and taking the difference (line 3):

> $E(X) = 0.5^1 + 2 \cdot0.5^2 + 3\cdot 0.5^3...\\$
>
> $0.5E(X) = 0.5^2 + 2 \cdot0.5^3 + 3\cdot 0.5^4...\\$
>
> $0.5E(X) = 0.5^1 + 0.5^2 + 0.5^3...$

My question: how did he calculate the difference on line 3?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This method is called "错位相减法" in Chinese, i.e. "Dislocation Subtraction", which is "almost everywhere" used to calculate the values of seires of the form $\sum P(n)q^n$ where $P$ is a polynoimal. See https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%94%99%E4%BD%8D%E7%9B%B8%E5%87%8F%E6%B3%95/7986491#reference-[1]-1177278-wrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$E = 0.5^1 + 2\cdot0.5^2 + 3\cdot0.5^3 + 4\cdot0.5^4+\cdots$$
$$0.5E = 0.5^2 + 2\cdot0.5^3 + 3\cdot0.5^4+\cdots$$
Combining terms with equal powers of $0.5$,$$E - 0.5E = 0.5^1 + 0.5^2(2-1) + 0.5^3(3-2) + 0.5^4 (4-3) \cdots$$
$$\implies 0.5E = 0.5^1 + 0.5^2+0.5^3\cdots$$

Answer (score 3):

Subtract the second line from the first line

$$0.5E(X)=E(x)-0.5E(X)=$$

$$ 0.5^1 + 2 \cdot0.5^2 + 3\cdot 0.5^3...\\$$

$$- 0.5^2 - 2 \cdot0.5^3 - 3\cdot 0.5^4...=$$

$$ 0.5^1 + 0.5^2 + 0.5^3...$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more "formal" way to write what you have, so it doesn't seem like so much of a trick. Since $$E(X) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{k}{2^k},$$ we have
\begin{align*}
    \frac{E(x)}{2} &= \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{k}{2^{k + 1}} \\
                   &= \sum_{k \geq 2} \frac{k - 1}{2^k} \\
                   &= \sum_{k \geq 2} \frac{k}{2^k} - \sum_{k \geq 2} \frac{1}{2^k} \\
                   &= E(x) - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
From this we can see that
\begin{equation*}
    E(x) = 2E(x) - 2,
\end{equation*}
or $E(x) = 2$.

This is something like a particularly nice example of the perturbation method to evaluate sums, which you can learn more about [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4205/files/CM3.pdf) or in various other sources online.

Comment: I think the reason for writing the OP in the way it was written is: to be understood by someone who does not know the $\Sigma$ notation.

Comment: @GEdgar Almost certainly. I only hoped to "peel back the curtain" a little bit, though perhaps I should direct OP to the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Notation) to learn more about what I've said if they're interested.

Comment: Something’s not right here. In the OP, E(x) is 2, not 1.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson You were absolutely right; I had left off the $k$ factor from OP's sum. Fortunately this only makes it a *slightly* more complicated example.